# Invalid Layer Save Flag - only ALL_SAVE_FLAGS is allowed with Android 9

Tags: android, android-studio, build.gradle, android-9.0-pie

I'm getting the following error when updating my targetSdkVersion to 28, the app that works perfectly in previous versions but specifically in android 9 gives me that error. I have seen several github links where they mention that the base bibliography was updated to 6.0.8, which I do not understand. Someone could tell me how to fix it. I am attaching the error I have in the Android Studio console.

```
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Invalid Layer Save Flag - only ALL_SAVE_FLAGS is allowed
        at android.graphics.Canvas.checkValidSaveFlags(Canvas.java:378)
        at android.graphics.Canvas.saveLayer(Canvas.java:455)
        at com.airbnb.lottie.model.layer.BaseLayer.draw(BaseLayer.java:222)
        at com.airbnb.lottie.model.layer.CompositionLayer.drawLayer(CompositionLayer.java:100)
        at com.airbnb.lottie.model.layer.BaseLayer.draw(BaseLayer.java:188)
        at com.airbnb.lottie.LottieDrawable.draw(LottieDrawable.java:300)
        at android.widget.ImageView.onDraw(ImageView.java:1360)
        at android.view.View.draw(View.java:20207)
        at android.view.View.buildDrawingCacheImpl(View.java:19478)
        at android.view.View.buildDrawingCache(View.java:19338)
        at android.view.View.draw(View.java:19927)
        at android.view.ViewGroup.drawChild(ViewGroup.java:4333)
        at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchDraw(ViewGroup.java:4112)
        at android.view.View.draw(View.java:20210)
        at android.view.View.updateDisplayListIfDirty(View.java:19082)
        at android.view.View.draw(View.java:19935)
        at android.view.ViewGroup.drawChild(ViewGroup.java:4333)
        at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchDraw(ViewGroup.java:4112)
        at android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout.dispatchDraw(ConstraintLayout.java:2023)
        at android.view.View.draw(View.java:20210)
        at android.view.View.updateDisplayListIfDirty(View.java:19082)
        at android.view.View.draw(View.java:19935)
        at android.view.ViewGroup.drawChild(ViewGroup.java:4333)
        at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchDraw(ViewGroup.java:4112)
        at android.view.View.updateDisplayListIfDirty(View.java:19073)
        at android.view.View.draw(View.java:19935)
        at android.view.ViewGroup.drawChild(ViewGroup.java:4333)
        at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchDraw(ViewGroup.java:4112)
        at android.view.View.updateDisplayListIfDirty(View.java:19073)
        at android.view.View.draw(View.java:19935)
        at android.view.ViewGroup.drawChild(ViewGroup.java:4333)
        at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchDraw(ViewGroup.java:4112)
        at android.view.View.updateDisplayListIfDirty(View.java:19073)
        at android.view.View.draw(View.java:19935)
        at android.view.ViewGroup.drawChild(ViewGroup.java:4333)
        at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchDraw(ViewGroup.java:4112)
        at android.view.View.updateDisplayListIfDirty(View.java:19073)
        at android.view.View.draw(View.java:19935)
        at android.view.ViewGroup.drawChild(ViewGroup.java:4333)
        at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchDraw(ViewGroup.java:4112)
        at android.view.View.draw(View.java:20210)
        at com.android.internal.policy.DecorView.draw(DecorView.java:780)
        at android.view.View.updateDisplayListIfDirty(View.java:19082)
        at android.view.ThreadedRenderer.updateViewTreeDisplayList(ThreadedRenderer.java:686)
        at android.view.ThreadedRenderer.updateRootDisplayList(ThreadedRenderer.java:692)
        at android.view.ThreadedRenderer.draw(ThreadedRenderer.java:801)
        at android.view.ViewRootImpl.draw(ViewRootImpl.java:3311)
        at android.view.ViewRootImpl.performDraw(ViewRootImpl.java:3115)
        at android.view.ViewRootImpl.performTraversals(ViewRootImpl.java:2484)
        at android.view.ViewRootImpl.doTraversal(ViewRootImpl.java:1460)
        at android.view.ViewRootImpl$TraversalRunnable.run(ViewRootImpl.java:7183)
        at android.view.Choreographer$CallbackRecord.run(Choreographer.java:949)
        at android.view.Choreographer.doCallbacks(Choreographer.java:761)
        at android.view.Choreographer.doFrame(Choreographer.java:696)
        at android.view.Choreographer$FrameDisplayEventReceiver.run(Choreographer.java:935)
        at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:873)
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:193)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6680)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
        at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:493)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:858)
```

Answer (score 16):

I had the same issue. It seems to be an android 9 problem. Resolved it by using:

```
implementation 'com.airbnb.android:lottie:2.7.0'
```

I hope it helps.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, I will try it, since I tried everything and did not find the solution.

Comment: Hi did you try the solution??

Comment: Yes, Sorry for the late reply, but it works perfectly @JohanFick

Answer (score 1):

I had the same issue with Glide SVG loader. To fix this you can migrate to the latest version 1.4 of AndroidSVG.

I updated the version to

implementation 'com.caverock:androidsvg-aar:1.4'

and the issue seems to be fixed for me.

Answer (score 0):

I faced this issue, I was using MaterialDrawer version 6.0.6, the only version from the v6 that doesn't has this problem is v6.0.9, you just have to change it on the gradle file.

Answer (score -1):

Resolved it by using in build.gradle:

```
targetSdkVersion 27
```